# Passing an ObjectOutputStream to another class

Tags: java, parameter-passing, objectoutputstream, objectinputstream

I am developing a GUI program to use in a client/server system that will save data in a `Vector`.  I have an `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` that is created when I make the connection, however I am not sure how to pass it into the new class when i try to open one up.  In my `Startup` class I have a `Serializable` object (`Message m`) that is created and passed into different classes to have different fields modified, as well as the connection gets established between the client and server

In my `Startup` class I have this code...

```
m.yourName = tmyName.getText();
m.department = tdepartment.getText();

if (m.yourName != null && m.department != null) {
    client = new Socket(server, port);
    oout = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
    oin = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
    toutput.setText("Connected");
    oout.writeObject(m);
    new WhatToDo (m, oout, oin);
}
```

In the `WhatToDo` class i have this code...

```
Message m;
ObjectOutputStream oout;
ObjectInputStream oin;

public WhatToDo(Message a, ObjectOutputStream oout2, ObjectInputStream oin2){
    m = new Message();
    m = a;

    // this is what i'm unsure about and need help with
    oout = oout2; //but need to construct oout first
    oin = oin2; //but need to construct oin first
}
```

If i do the new `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` like I did in `Startup`, i will create a new connection to the server.  I wish to use the existing `Streams` created in `Startup` in `WhatToDo`.  Thank you for your help in advance!

I'm using an `ActionListener` with button presses, so the streams will need to be saved in the constructor for later use in the `ActionListener`.

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: Whatever you are doing looks alright. Except that you are missing `;`s on the last to statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wish to use the existing Streams

That is exactly what your code does now. Your comments about 'but need to construct' are incorrect.

Comment: thank you I was worried about using them without constructing them (null pointer error) but that doesn't seem to be the case here. THank you